# How to retrieve object elements from a list

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to retrieve some data from a couple of parse tables using parse cloud code.

```
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("getData", parameters, new FunctionCallback<List>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List results, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        for (ParseObject country : results) {

                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

The `List results` returns all the data from all the tables included in the cloud code. But I don't know how to access them.

Here is the data that the `arrayList` retrieves:

```
       [{startup=com.parse.ParseObject@1480b86a, 
    resolvedRelations=
    {advisors=[com.parse.ParseObject@3efb015b, com.parse.ParseObject@32ab7df8, com.parse.ParseObject@393662d1], 
activeSyndicate= {investors=[com.parse.ParseObject@2ce9f136, com.parse.ParseObject@2cde5837, com.parse.ParseObject@b1681a4, com.parse.ParseObject@3ced5b0d, com.parse.ParseObject@3bdbeac2]}, 
    images=[com.parse.ParseObject@123640d3, com.parse.ParseObject@3f0c1410], 
    founders=[com.parse.ParseObject@1aa19b09, com.parse.ParseObject@601f10e, com.parse.ParseObject@251a172f], 
    tags=[com.parse.ParseObject@1c86613c, com.parse.ParseObject@73fdec5, com.parse.ParseObject@1d70101a, com.parse.ParseObject@3bbaf74b, com.parse.ParseObject@34f65528, com.parse.ParseObject@1fc4a241, com.parse.ParseObject@2f6f13e6]}}
```

The `ArrayList` returns objects, but I need `ParseObject`. Help please.

Comment: Why can't you just use country.startup for example ? 
Anyway, It seems like the 1st parameter should be: 
done(List<ParseObject > results, ParseException e)...

Comment: @azerto00 `country` is an uninitialized variable. And when I try the 1st parameter `List<ParseObject>` I get the following error : `java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.parse.ParseObject`

Comment: I don't know the type of results. Do you have any information ? Maybe HashMap<String, ParseObject> ?

Comment: the type of results is array of objects

Comment: the array consists of other arrays of objects inside and i want to know how can i access these objects one by one